# How can I fix my understanding of Numerical Analysis?

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, self-learning, book-recommendation

I am an undergraduate student taking Numerical Analysis. I’m having a hard time understanding some of the material because it feels as though my instructor is jumping all over the place. When it comes to the applied problems I understand them and can complete them. But when he does a proof in class it’s hard to follow. Now he started giving proofs in the homework and I am getting stuck because I don’t feel I have a good grasp on the theory. To give you an idea of where our class is at, we are covering Secant Method. I took an Introduction to Real Analysis course where we covered up to Uniform Continuity and I felt that I was able to understand the proofs well. This class feels different for some reason. Does anybody have any book recommendations or resources that can make understanding the proofs easier?

Comment: I have one book to recommend: Endre Suli and David Mayers, "An introduction to Numerical Analysis", Cambridge University Press, 2003. For complementary reading: David Kincaid and Ward Cheney, "Numerical Analysis. Mathematics  of Scientific Computing", Brooks/Cole Publishing Company, 1996. I hope this helps.

Comment: The back and forth between methods and theory is building your cognitive skills. Keep up the struggle, and thank your instructor. You’re moving beyond formative knowledge towards insight.